# I use free admin template and configured routes and works fine, but when i try to use mobile sidebar collapse not work. How to solve this in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

[![How to disappear sidebar view after click Link located within sidebar][I need to collapse this sidebar Link after click in React JS and Router-dom]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CnGM.png)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const SideBar = () => {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

const onOpen = () => {
setOpen(!open);
};
 return (
 <div className="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion    menu-shadow " data-scroll-to-active="true" data-img="theme-assets/images/backgrounds/02.jpg">
<div className="navbar-header">
  <ul className="nav navbar-nav flex-row">       
    <li className="nav-item mr-auto">
      <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand" onClick={onOpen}>
          <img className="brand-logo" alt="Chameleon admin logo" src="theme-assets/images/logo/logo.png"/>
          <h3 className="brand-text">LaravelTricks</h3>
      </Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div className="main-menu-content">
  <ul className="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
    <li className="active"><Link to="/"><i className="ft-home"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Dashboard</span></Link>
    </li>
    <li className=" nav-item"><Link to="/to-do-list"><i className="ft-pie-chart"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Tasks</span></Link>
    </li>
    <li className=" nav-item"><Link to="/"><i className="la la-sign-out"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Logout</span></Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div className="navigation-background"></div>
```

); }export default SideBar;

Answer (score 0):

To collapse the sidebar after clicking on a link located within the sidebar you need to update the state of open to false in the onOpen func which is called when the Link is clicked. Here's the updated code:

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideBar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  const onOpen = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={`main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow ${open ? '' : 'menu-collapsed'}`} data-scroll-to-active="true" data-img="theme-assets/images/backgrounds/02.jpg">
      <div className="navbar-header">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav flex-row">       
          <li className="nav-item mr-auto">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand" onClick={onOpen}>
              <img className="brand-logo" alt="Chameleon admin logo" src="theme-assets/images/logo/logo.png"/>
              <h3 className="brand-text">LaravelTricks</h3>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="main-menu-content">
        <ul className="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
          <li className="active"><Link to="/"><i className="ft-home"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Dashboard</span></Link></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/to-do-list" onClick={onOpen}><i className="ft-pie-chart"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Tasks</span></Link></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/" onClick={onOpen}><i className="la la-sign-out"></i><span className="menu-title" data-i18n="">Logout</span></Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="navigation-background"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

Comment: It doesnt work, i Updated but still not working.., please can you help me